# Is there a non-verbatim form of lstinline from the listings package?

Tags: beamer, listings, verbatim

I'm using the `listings` package with `beamer` and I'd like to try to avoid making frames `fragile` where possible. I know that many of my frames will need to be `fragile` but there are some where the contents of my `lstinline` code need not switch to a `verbatim` processing style. Let me illustrate this with an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C++}
\lstset{frame=,
  framesep=5pt,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=[1]\ttfamily\color{blue}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\ttfamily\color{purple}\bfseries,
  commentstyle=\normalfont\color{green},
  stringstyle=\color{brown}\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  fontadjust=true,
}

\newcommand*{\identifier}[1]{{\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{purple}\bfseries #1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]{1. Hello world}
        \begin{lstlisting}
        int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
            std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]{2. Discussion of Hello world}
        Note that \lstinline!cout! in the previous example means ``console out''.
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{3. Discussion of Hello world}
        Note that \identifier{cout} in the previous example means ``console out''.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There are three frames here, frame 1 is necessarily `fragile`. Frame 2 has to be made `fragile` otherwise there is an error, even though there is no content in that frame that needs to be processed `verbatim`. Frame 3 shows the same output as frame 2 without using `fragile`. However, this is very limited as it means controlling everything myself rather than getting `listings` to do it for me. This would be much harder when I start wanting to talk about expressions that contain both keywords and identifiers, for example.

**Question** Hence, I am wondering if there is a version of the `lstinline` command, that does not switch to a `verbatim`-style processing mode, and therefore frame 2 would not require use of `fragile`. If not, would this be extremely difficult to provide?

Comment: The job of `\lstinline` *is* to switch to a sort of verbatim mode in order to allow interpreting specially keywords, variable names, delimiters and whatnot.

Comment: @egreg I understand _why_ `\lstinline` switches to a verbatim-style mode, and I understand that normally that is a good thing. Are you suggesting that even for simple `code`, `\lstinlinenoverb{code}` is not achievable (or more likely, not worth the effort)? Is the verbatim-mode inseparable from the syntax highlighting etc?

Comment: For single identifiers like `cout` your approach of defining a special macro is the way to go, IMO. There's no way of colorizing arbitrary constructs without switching to a special mode, which thus requires `[fragile]`.

Comment: use `\texttt{...}` for small pieces of code. Then you do not need the fragile option.

Comment: @Herbert. Thanks, I had already considered that (similar to my `\identifier` definition), but it means that if I want the code to appear with the same syntax highlighting as proper `listings` output, I have to manually emulate what `listings` does.

Comment: @cyberSingularity: yes, but that is not a big deal if you use it not too often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `\lstinline` directly in your `\identifier` command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C++}
\lstset{frame=,
  framesep=5pt,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=[1]\ttfamily\color{blue}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\ttfamily\color{purple}\bfseries,
  commentstyle=\normalfont\color{green},
  stringstyle=\color{brown}\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  fontadjust=true,
}

\newcommand*{\identifier}[1]{\lstinline!#1!}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{1. Hello world}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{2. Discussion of Hello world}
  Note that \lstinline!cout << "Hello"! in the previous example means
  ``console out''.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{3. Discussion of Hello world}
  Note that \identifier{cout << "Hello"} in the previous example means
  ``console out''.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Braces in the argument of `\identifier` will not appear.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using either this (but was for some reason not entirely satisfied with it, forgot why though, so am more accepting of it now!) or using `fragile=singleslide` (which I think prevents me using overlays, but I don't find the `beamer` manual very clear about `fragile` restrictions). @egreg's comments about having to ensure everything inside the argument to `\identifier` has the right catcode already is a useful reminder too, though I think having braces in the argument is more likely to produce odd errors than just disappearing characters.

Comment: @egreg Obviously, `\identifier` is not a true verbatim command. But here, if I understand the question, the goal is to get a non verbatim command that produces the same colored and formated output that the `\lstinline` verbatim command (for simple code).

Answer (score 2):

The workings of `listings` require changing the category code of characters and so the `[fragile]` option after `\begin{frame}` is necessary.

It all depends on what you really need to type: a small number of identifiers can be input as you do with `\identifier`. You can make other definitions for colorizing common constructs, so as to limit the need of `[fragile]`.